# Nexus excluding entire artifacts from springsource repos

Tags: spring, maven, cloud-foundry, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to add the Springsource maven repos as a proxy repo in my nexus installiation and it is only including the org/springframework artifacts from there.  I can't resolve anything else.  I need to be able to resolve:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
        <artifactId>cloudfoundry-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

http://repo.springsource.org/milestone/org/cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-runtime/0.8.2/

Does anyone know why nexus is not including org/cloudfoundry?  The proxy repo config is the default config with url of:
http://repo.springsource.org/milestone

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a useful fellow over at the [hipchat nexus community](https://links.sonatype.com/products/nexus/community-chat), I got this problem solved.  I THINK what the problem was is that the spring repos weren't in my public repo group config.  They looked like they were there, but it's possible I never hit save after moving them in there.  What led me to discover this was by loading this url in my browser:
http://yourdomain.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/cloudfoundry/cloudfoundry-runtime/0.8.2/cloudfoundry-runtime-0.8.2.pom?describe

That will spit out a bunch of json and it listed the repos that were searched.  In there is was obvious the spring repos weren't being searched, so I went back to the config, added them, and hit SAVE this time for sure and then I could resolve the dependency!